# selector para cambiar texto dentro de un TD sin eliminar otros elementos en el mismo nodo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con jquery y estoy intentando acceder al segundo TD de una tabla en un evento especifico dada la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
<table id="reg-01082-2020-Dic-03" style="max-width: 100%;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Registro para la fecha de Vencimiento: <b> Fet Med Herb 8/6oz (01082) = 2020-Dic-03 </b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>#reg</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Peso</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="content-reg-01082-2020-Dic-03">
        <tr data-line="01082-2020-Dic-03-1" class="text-danger font-weight-bold blink-xs">
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td class="t-right">100<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrc-01082-2020-Dic-03-1" value="100"></td>
            <td class="t-right">136.08<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrw-01082-2020-Dic-03-1" value="136.08"></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" name="act-reg" data-target="01082-2020-Dic-03-1" disabled="disabled">Modificar</button></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger disabled" name="rem-reg" id="" disabled="disabled">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-line="01082-2020-Dic-03-2" class="">
            <td class="text-center">2</td>
            <td class="t-right">150<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrc-01082-2020-Dic-03-2" value="150"></td>
            <td class="t-right">204.12<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrw-01082-2020-Dic-03-2" value="204.12"></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="act-reg" data-target="01082-2020-Dic-03-2">Modificar</button></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="rem-reg" id="">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-line="01082-2020-Dic-03-3" class="">
            <td class="text-center">3</td>
            <td class="t-right">125<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrc-01082-2020-Dic-03-3" value="125"></td>
            <td class="t-right">170.10<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrw-01082-2020-Dic-03-3" value="170.10"></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="act-reg" data-target="01082-2020-Dic-03-3">Modificar</button></td>
            <td class="t-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="rem-reg" id="">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

como podrán observar en la tabla existe este tag: `data-line="01082-2020-Dic-03-1"` al cual en el javascript tengo acceso.

pero lo que necesito es saltar de este elemento al **segundo** TD que contiene texto y un input; para cambiar el texto y el valor del input.

```
<td class="t-right">100<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="i-text-lrc-01082-2020-Dic-03-1" value="100"></td>
```

**nota:** en este punto del código encontré que puedo acceder al texto:

```
jQuery(".dname").find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

pero como evito eliminar el input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera:

- Necesitas ponerle un ID específico al input que quieres modificar
- Necesitas ponerle un ID al TD que quieres modificar

Supongamos que le pusiste un ID "inputChange" al input y un ID "tdChange" al TD

```
$("#cambiar").on("click", () => {
   $("#tdChange").html($("#tdChange").html().replace("200", "nuevo texto"));
$("#inputChange").Val("Nuevo valor");
    console.log($("#tdChange").html());
});
});
```

Esto cambiará el texto del TD sin modificar el HTML, y al mismo tiempo cambiar el valor del input.

He hecho el siguiente código y funciona bien, no reemplaza el input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="" content="">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tdChange">
      200
      <input id="inputChange" />
    </div>
    <button id="cambiar" type="submit">A</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $("#cambiar").on("click", () => {
    $("#tdChange").html($("#tdChange").html().replace("200", "nuevo texto"));
    console.log($("#tdChange").html());
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Edit

Dado el caso que no puedes cambiar el HTML, he basado mi respuesta en [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements/4106957)

Puedes usar el siguiente código cuando necesites cambiar el texto sin alterar los otros elementos del nodo

```
const = txt = changeTd.childNodes[0];

txt.nodeValue = 'texto';
```

Puedes añadir esto en el evento en el que quieres modificar el texto del nodo sin modificar los elementos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="" content="">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tdChange">
      200
      <input id="inputChange" />
    </div>
    <button id="cambiar" type="submit">A</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("#cambiar").on("click", () => {
     var your_div = document.getElementById('tdChange');

var text_to_change = your_div.childNodes[0];

text_to_change.nodeValue = 'new text'; })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no es lo que busco ... te tomaste el tiempo de leer que datos tengo ??? y que me hace falta solo el selector para cambiar el Texto de un TD???

Comment: como veras el haber un texto y un input es lo que complica un poco la cosa ya que al modificar el texto se borra el input ... me veo obligado a hacerlo en ese orden:

Comment: cambiar texto -> cambiar input value -> trigger update/insert en el backend... asi va la cosa XD

Comment: otro dato el html que vez no puedo cambiarlo... de lo contrario hubiera movido el input que es lo que me estorba

Comment: Si no puedes cambiar el HTML puedes crear un `<div>` para referirte a el con jQuery y cambiar desde ahí su HTML, entonces no estaríamos borrando el input

Comment: solo necesito cambiar el texto no debo tocar nada mas ...

Comment: ¿[Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements/4106957) solucina tu inconveniente?

Comment: creo que si déjame probarlo

Comment: si funciona actualizas tu respuesta???

Comment: Haré un edit en unos momentos.